# ¿Cómo hacer música en la consola de C++?

Tags: c++

Se supone que debería sonar una melodía al ejecutar el programa pero no es así, ¿qué debo hacer para que suene?

```
#include <windows.h>   //For Beep & Sleep functions
#include <stdlib.h>  //For System Pause
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(700);
    Beep (196,100);Sleep(700);
    Beep (262,300);Sleep(300);
    Beep (196,300);Sleep(300);
    Beep (164,300);Sleep(300);
    Beep (220,300);Sleep(100);
    Beep (246,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (233,200);
    Beep (220,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (196,100);Sleep(150);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(150);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(150);
    Beep (440,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (349,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (294,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (247,100);Sleep(500);
    Beep (262,300);Sleep(300);
    Beep (196,300);Sleep(300);
    Beep (164,300);Sleep(300);
    Beep (220,300);Sleep(100);
    Beep (246,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (233,200);
    Beep (220,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (196,100);Sleep(150);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(150);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(150);
    Beep (440,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (349,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (294,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (247,100);Sleep(900);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (370,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (349,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (311,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (207,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (220,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (220,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (294,100);Sleep(500);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (370,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (349,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (311,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (523,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (523,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (523,100);Sleep(1100);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (370,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (349,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (311,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (207,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (220,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (220,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (294,100);Sleep(500);
    Beep (311,300);Sleep(300);
    Beep (296,300);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,300);Sleep(1300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (294,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (330,200);Sleep(50);
    Beep (262,200);Sleep(50);
    Beep (220,200);Sleep(50);
    Beep (196,100);Sleep(700);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (294,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(700);
    Beep (440,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(500);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (294,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (330,200);Sleep(50);
    Beep (262,200);Sleep(50);
    Beep (220,200);Sleep(50);
    Beep (196,100);Sleep(700);
    /*Intro*/
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(700);
    Beep (196,100);Sleep(700);
    Beep (196,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (523,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (660,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (784,100);Sleep(575);
    Beep (660,100);Sleep(575);
    Beep (207,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (311,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (415,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (523,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (622,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (830,100);Sleep(575);
    Beep (622,100);Sleep(575);
    Beep (233,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (294,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (349,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (466,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (587,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (698,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (932,100);Sleep(575);
    Beep (932,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (932,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (932,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (1046,675);

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: creo q deberias eliminar muchos sleep y aumentarle 50 a los beeps con 100 milisegundos

Comment: Super Mario!!!! :-) ¿Te genera algún error, suena 'mal' o simplemente no suena nada? Mírate  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx, el soporte y la implementación depende de la versión del sistema operativo que uses, originalmente esta función trabajaba con el altavoz interno incorporado, que no esta presente en muchos sistemas actuales. Se ha reimplementado para que se redirija al dispositivo de sonido por defecto,  en win10 con tarjeta de sonido funciona sin problemas por ejemplo.

Answer (score 2):

`Beep` retorna un booleano que indica si todo ha ido bien (`true`) o si se ha producido un error (`false`). En caso de ir todo bien, si no suena tal vez pueda deberse a que tu equipo no tiene altavoz interno o que este, por alguna razón, está silenciado. Si se ha producido un error podrás obtener más información acerca del mismo mediante la función `GetLastError`.

Por otro lado, la función `Sleep` puede ser peligrosa para tus intereses. Esta función *duerme*  el proceso durante **al menos** el tiempo indicado. Digo **al menos** porque la función no garantiza que el hilo vuelva a ponerse en marcha justo después del tiempo indicado, sino que pasado ese plazo el hilo vuelve a entrar en la cola de ejecución del Sistema Operativo que será el que, en última instancia, decidirá cuándo volverá a tener un hilo de ejecución.

El efecto que puedes tener es una música errática y desacompasada (sobretodo si la carga del procesador es alta con varias tareas con la misma prioridad que tu proceso).

Para mitigar este efecto deberías implementar una espera activa. Lee la fecha del sistema, suma el intervalo de espera y mete la ejecución en un `while` hasta que coincidan las horas. Una posibilidad:

```
void EsperaActiva(DWORD espera)
{
  DWORD sleep = GetTickCount() + espera;
  while( GetTickCount() < sleep );
}
```